# ASP.NET Core 6.0 - Getting Dynamic Json Object From appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, appsettings

My appsettings.json file looks like the below. In my program.cs I want to extract the Request config section as a Json object (using newtonsoft.json). I cannot map it to an custom .NET object as the structure & content of the Request section would be different in different environments in which the asp.net web API runs - hence I need to extract it as a JObject. How can I do it? I could not find any way of converting a ConfigSection to a Json object

**appsettings.json**

```json
{
    "ProductConfiguration":
    {
      "CapabilityName": "Tester",
      "Request":
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Content":
        {
          "User": "TestUser"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I tried JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(service.GetSection("RequestJson")))
but the result was null / not correct

Comment: Put the `appsettings.json` file along with the complete code you tried

Answer (score 3):

From the .NET configuration [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration):

> Configuration providers read configuration data from key-value pairs using various configuration sources

So you should view configuration as set of key-value pairs, not as JSON (not all providers are JSON). If you don't have arrays in the config you can try to do something like the following (I'm using `System.Text.Json` but if needed this can be migrated to Newtonsoft):

```
var configurationSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ProductConfiguration");

var root = new JsonObject();
foreach (var (key, s) in configurationSection.AsEnumerable())
{
    JsonNode r = root;
    var keys = key.Split(":");
    foreach (var el in keys[..^1])
    {
        if (r[el] == null)
        {
            r[el] = new JsonObject();
        }

        r = r[el];
    }

    var last = keys[^1];
    if (r[last] == null)
    {
        r[last] = s;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(root.ToJsonString()); // {"ProductConfiguration":{"Request":{"Id":"1","Content":{"User":"TestUser"}},"CapabilityName":"Tester"}}
```

But in general I would recommend using the provided configuration APIs (like `AsEnumerable`, `GetChildren`, etc.) to read values dynamically and/or determine object types to bind it too. Also in some cases `Dictionary<string, string>` can be used.

Also you can always just read the file and parse it as JSON without using the configuration APIs (but in this case you will lose some benefits like environment configs and using other config sources).

Comment: Works like a charme. A bit strange:  `configurationSection.AsEnumerable()` returns in reverse alphabetical order. I added `configurationSection.AsEnumerable().Reverse()` to have it from a to z

Answer (score 0):

you may use the following code to traverse a configuration section to get all its key values as an object

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<ValuesController> logger;

    public ValuesController(IConfiguration configuration,ILogger<ValuesController> logger)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    // GET: api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            string ParentKey = "ElsticConfig";
            var json = GetConfigSectionAsJson(ParentKey);

            // access JsonObject
            //string? value = json["DataViewsDictionary"]?["General Logs"]?.ToString();

            return Ok(json.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogCritical(ex, ex.ToString());
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new { message = ex.ToString() });
        }

    }


    private JsonObject GetConfigSectionAsJson(string ParentKey)
    {
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        var configurationSection = configuration.GetSection(ParentKey);
        GetConfigInernal(ParentKey, configurationSection, obj);
        return obj;
    }

    private void GetConfigInernal(string parentKey, IConfigurationSection section , JsonObject obj)
    {
        object value = section.Value;
        string key = section.Key.Replace($"{parentKey}:", "");
        if (value is string)
        {
            // The value is a string
            obj.Add(key, value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            // The value is an object
            foreach (var newSec in section.GetChildren())
            {
                if (newSec.Value is string)
                {
                    GetConfigInernal(newSec.Path, newSec, obj);
                }
                else
                {
                    var newObj = new JsonObject();
                    GetConfigInernal(newSec.Path, newSec, newObj);
                    obj.Add(newSec.Key, newObj);
                }
            }
        }

        //logger.LogInformation(obj.ToString());
        

    }
}
```